# How to track Adsense Click With Javascript

Tags: javascript, adsense

I try to track user clicks in my google adsense. I have a blog with these ads. I created a code, it works with any other things, but dont work with google adsense.

I want that the console.log() return "true"!

```
    <script>

    var clicou = document.getElementById("ads1").addEventListener("click", function(){

        clique(true);


    function clique(pixel) {
        console.log(pixel);

    }

    </script>
```

I put the code adsense in a `<div>` with id ads1.

Comment: Why don't you use the Google AdSense dashboard to see the activity of your ads?

Comment: I want that a function work when a user click in a adsense!